# How to use mapping variable value in the same mapping?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have two files-
File1- Data
File2- Period (for which date the data needs to be loaded)
There is no common column between the two files.
How can i take the period from file 2 and use it for file1 insertion in the same mapping?
Please suggest some approach

```
File 1
ID    Value
AS5   0.5688
AS8   0.9823
AS1   0.5678

File 2
Period
202007


Target
Period     ID   Value
01-jan-20  AS1  0.2981
01-jan-20  AS7  0.4353
01-Feb-20  AS8  0.2343
```

Comment: It depends on the data set. Can you share sample data set from both the files?

Comment: Your `File1` and `File2` data doesn't match with `Target` data. On what basis are you loading the target?

Comment: This is just an example. The target data which i have shown is for Jan and Feb period.July data is what i have to load in target from FILE1 and FILE 2

Comment: Generic approach may be - use File2 as a source, use aggregator to get maximum period. Then use file1 as source and join with above flow on a dummy join/link condition(create a dummy column on both flow). And then pull data from File1 and file2 into Target.